# htaccess hide subdirectory from url after redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, redirect

I have same application running in local server - one in 'localhost', another in 'localhost/bss/'. My domains port forwarded to them. So www.domain.com:1111 and sub.domain2.info:1111 points to localhost. Now both of them showing localhost. I need to redirect sub.domain2.info:1111 (localhost) to sub.domain2.com:1111/bss/ (localhost/bss) but dont want to see '/bss'

My .htaccess in localhost is currently like this -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Options -Indexes 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)sub.domain2.info:1111$
RewriteRule (.*) /bss/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Nothing particular in .htaccess in localhost/bss -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Options -Indexes
```

I would highly appreciate your response. Tried a few but nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Apache Server for achieving this. If you are working on local environments you can try out with Virtual Hosts also
Can you try this for your Subdomain

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain2\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bss
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bss/$1 [L]
```

Adding this by seeing your comment you can set up  [virtualhosts in linux](http://septiadi.com/read/add-new-virtual-host-xampp-or-lampp-on-linux)

*By the way, I didn't understand why you using these ports in domain names*

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. Its a public port forwarded, so don't I have to put ':1111' like '.com:1111$' perhaps? The thing is i tried both with or without port..added that code in .htaccess inside subdirectory (localhost/bss/) but its still showing sub.domain.com:1111/bss/
And virtualhost edit ain't working for some reason in my centos server. I am working with xampp in centos.